# ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to build a currency converter using an ArrayAdapter. But I get this error! Does anyone know how to fix that? ***I have checked other posts here but nothing seems to work.*** I was following a tutorial on youtube but the dev didnt have this problem. A friend of mine did the same tutorial and we have the same code but her project works fine...dunno whats wrong with it

```
01-03 20:05:20.242 5183-5183/? E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
01-03 20:05:20.243 5183-5183/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-03 20:05:20.245 5183-5183/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.android.example.currencyconverter2, PID: 5183
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:393)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194)
                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:580)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:418)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369) 
                                                     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:194) 
                                                     at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:580) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:418) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715) 
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748) 
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951) 
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643) 
                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxCallback;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxStatus;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText InputCurrency;
private Spinner ConvertFrom;
private Spinner ConvertToC;
private Button btnConvert;
private TextView CFtextView;
private TextView CTtextView;
private String fixer_url ="http://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols="; //USD,GBP
private AQuery aq;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    InputCurrency =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputEditText);
    ConvertFrom = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.fspinner);
    ConvertToC = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Tspinner);
    btnConvert = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);
    CFtextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CFtextView);
    CTtextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CTtextView);
    aq = new AQuery(this);


            // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.currencies_array,     android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
                ConvertFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
                ConvertToC.setAdapter(adapter);
```

gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.example.currencyconverter2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.8.jar')
}
```

Comment: you may want to run a diff on your file vs your friends to locate the error/difference

Comment: @happymacarts how to do that?

Comment: an external utility depends on your OS here is a [webbased one](https://www.diffchecker.com/) I have never used it. but you should do a search for [diff tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=diff+tools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of `ArrayAdapter#createFromResource` should be an identifier of a layout with only a TextView in it, if I understand the documentation, the examples and your error messages correctly.
For example, use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.

The problem is that the layout you use (`andoid.R.layout.activity_list_item`) has a RelativeLayout as the root view.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)). The last parameter of createFromResource() needs to be the layout id of the `TextView`:

Create this my_item_layout.xml file in your layouts folder:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/item_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:paddingTop="1dp"
      android:paddingBottom="1dp"
      android:paddingStart="8dp"
      android:paddingEnd="8dp"/>
```

And in your adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.currencies_array, R.layout.my_item_layout);
```

Comment: getting this error: Expected resource of type layout. Cannot resolve symbol 'CFtextView'.

Comment: Maybe it would be simpler for you to provide your own layout and not use built in layout. This way you'll have more control and can provide your own id.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Thank you that solved it! Can you explain me why tho?

Comment: It was expecting a TextView and the android.R.layout.activity_list_item does not have it as root element.

Answer (score 0):

"android.R.layout.activity_list_item" is a linearlayout. createFromResource(..) is expecting Textview as its 3rd argument. Try using "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" instead. The layout should just have TextView and shouldn't be wrapped inside Linearlayout.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.currencies_array,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Comment: im not using any linear layout

Comment: "android.R.layout.activity_list_item" that you used has Linearlayout as the rootview.